# Reversing a content array

Tags: ember.js

I'm storing a list of search terms in my ArrayController. I'd like the search terms to be displayed newest to oldest. By default Ember outputs them in order.

You can see my current implementation here: http://andymatthews.net/code/emberTweets/

And here's the pertinent code.

```
{{#each App.recentUsersArray.reverse}}
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="view again" {{action "searchAgain" target="App.recentUsersArray"}}>{{this}}</a>
    </li>
{{/each}}

App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    reverse: function(){
        return this.content.reverse();
    }.property(),
});
```

You can see that I'm trying to reverse it using a property() method but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always use `get` and `set` to access properties. Also if a computed property depends on other ones, you have to add these in the `property` declaration. The use of `cacheable` can be omitted in the next release of ember, see [discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/38). You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b3waY/).

```
reverse: function(){
    return this.get('content').toArray().reverse();
}.property('content.@each').cacheable()
```

You could also use the `unshiftObject` method on an array and hereby circumvent creating a computed property, see http://jsfiddle.net/ez7bV/.

Comment: I know this is old but reverseObjects() is available and it works just like reverse() but is KVO-compliant.

Comment: `reverseObjects` appears to be the blessed way to do this: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_reverseObjects . Note that it's part of `Ember.MutableArray`.